# How do I document immediate invocation + anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, jsdoc

Using JSDoc, how do I document this code?

```
var mynamespace = {};

/**
 * What do I put here?
 */
mynamespace.myfunc = (function () {
    var i = 0;
    /**
     * Do I need to put anything here?
     */
    return function (a) {
        return a + i++;
    };
}());
```

The signature in this case could be:

```
/**
 * @param {Number} base
 * @return {Number}
 */
```

I'm using the Google Closure Compiler and it doesn't like JSDoc near `return function () {`. I'm guessing there must be a proper way to do this. I guess my real question is: "how do I shut up GCC?" :p

I looked around a bit but I didn't find this situation exactly. I would imagine it's quite common.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you use the signature you propose?

Comment: Yes, the exact error message is: `[file].js:[line]: WARNING - Misplaced function annotation. This JSDoc is not attached to a function node. Are you missing parentheses?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a JSDoc pro but I could suggest you something

First I suggest initializing the `i` variable to 0 to not have a `NaN` value return by your function. But that's just details of the code and not relevant for your question about commenting according to JSDoc.

Maybe you should organize your code this way to "shut up" GCC :

```
var mynamespace = {};

/**
 * Display the value we pass with a counter incremented each time we call the method
 * @name myFunc
 * @params {Number} a - value to add to the counter
 * @return {Number} addition of a and i++
 */
mynamespace.myfunc = (function () {
    var i;
    /**
     * @alias myFunc
     */
    function add(a) {
        return a + i++; 
    };
    return add;
}());
```

It could be because you return an anonymous function.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** :

I found out that the @alias tag could make the deal. Maybe you can try with the code I edited in the code snippet.

[More details](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html)

Comment: Removing the direct return, and naming the function, works to shut up the gcc warning. I'm not sure I agree with the jsDoc for the IIFE, it seems to imply that `myfunc` returns a function, which it does not.

Comment: As for `i` not being initialized, don't worry about it, it's just a bogus implementation.

Comment: You are right the myFunc return not a function, so we could use the same return as the add function?

Comment: I have edited my post. The @alias tag could make the deal.

Comment: I'm not sure if `@alias` and `@name` are recognized by Closure. I think it may be possible to make Closure do the right thing by spamming inline type casts all over the place, but I'm not sure what the *right* approach is.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: As per your comment, you can get GCC to shut up by "silencing warnings". See here: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings#warnings-level-api

The rest of my answer is about documenting JavaScript, not necessarily the internals of JSDoc.

I would suggest writing the (outer) anonymous function as a named function declaration below. The docs for this function should be a normal function, with a return type of function, noting that it will be expounded upon momentarily.

Assign the namespaced attribute to the result of invoking that function. Document here your new namespaced function, just like a normal function.

IIFE's are great demonstrations of JS's power, but for readability... eh. IIFE's are ultimately unnecessary (I'm like 95% on that claim, would love to see a counter example).

```
var mynamespace = {};

/**
 * A brand new safe, private, lovely closure
 * 
 * @param {Number} 
 * @return {Number} Will always be NaN since i was never defined? ;)
 */  
mynamespace.myfunc = factory();

/**
 * Factory for safe, private, lovely closure
 *
 * @return {Function} A fresh closure
 */    
function factory() {
    var i;

    // Return new closure (see signature above)
    return function (a) {
        return a + i++;
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't want to silence gcc entirely. Rewriting as you suggest does not seem like a good idea to me. The warning gcc gives is about the jsDoc surround `return function () {`, that doesn't seem to be resolved yet.

Comment: Alright, thanks for making it clear. I'm not a JSDoc user so I'm no more help. Good luck!